# change QCompleter result in QLineEdit

Tags: qt

The `QLineEdit` is for entering post code. User may also input city name, while `QCompleter` will display a list of names for user to select. The problem is, on selecting the name in completer, how could the post code be put in the `QLineEdit`?
I tried to connect `QCompleter::activated`(`QModelIndex`) to slot that change the `QLineEdit` text to post code. But later the text was again set to city name by `QLineEdit`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry, my previous answer was not correct, so I've edited it.

As the documentation says:

> QString QCompleter::pathFromIndex ( const QModelIndex & index ) const
> [virtual]
>
> Returns the path for the given index. The completer object
> uses this to obtain the completion text from the underlying model. The
> default implementation returns the edit role of the item for list
> models. It returns the absolute file path if the model is a QDirModel.

I've got what you need by subclassing `QCompleter` and reimplementing `pathFromIndex`:

```
class CodeCompleter : public QCompleter
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit CodeCompleter(QObject *parent = 0);
    
    static const int CompleteRole;

    QString pathFromIndex(const QModelIndex &index) const;
};

const int CodeCompleter::CompleteRole = Qt::UserRole + 1;

CodeCompleter::CodeCompleter(QObject *parent) :
    QCompleter(parent)
{

}

QString
CodeCompleter::pathFromIndex(const QModelIndex &index) const
{
    QMap<int, QVariant> data = model()->itemData(index);
    QString code = data.value(CompleteRole).toString();
    return code;
}
```

And you can use it like this:

```
QStringList cities;
    cities << "Moscow" << "London" << "Las Vegas" << "New York";

    QStandardItemModel *model = new QStandardItemModel;
    for (int i = 0; i < cities.count(); ++i)
    {
        QString city = cities.at(i);
        QString code = city.at(0) + QString::number(city.length());///< just an example

        QStandardItem *item = new QStandardItem;
        item->setText(city);
        item->setData(code, CodeCompleter::CompleteRole);

        model->appendRow(item);
    }

    QLineEdit *lineEdit = new QLineEdit(this);

    CodeCompleter *completer = new CodeCompleter(this);
    completer->setModel(model);
    completer->setCaseSensitivity(Qt::CaseInsensitive);
    lineEdit->setCompleter(completer);
```

Comment: with 'setCompletionRole(CompleteRole)', user has to input post code for completer hints rather than the name.