# Make QCompleter search in QStandardItemModel "data" instead "text"

Tags: c++, qt

I am using a `QCompleter` with a `QStandardItemModel` as a model.

The code goes something like this:

```
QStandardItemModel *modelProtocolName = new QStandardItemModel();
QStringList list;
list << "one" << "two" << "three";
for (int i = 0; i < list.length(); i++)
{
    QStandardItem *item = new QStandardItem();
    item->setText( list.at( i ) );
    item->setData( "real one, two or three is inserted here", ZAdvancedCompleter::CompleteRole );
    modelProtocolName->appendRow( item );
}
ZAdvancedCompleter completerProtocolName = new ZAdvancedCompleter( this );
completerProtocolName->setModel( modelProtocolName );
```

Now when I use the `QCompleter` it searches in the list, i.e. in "one", "two" and "three". Is it possible to direct the search to the data of the model?

Comment: Check this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14373930/1465625

Comment: Actually I've read this and it works so far that the correct value (from data) is put into the QLineEdit after selection. But during typing it still searches in text and not in data, any idea how this can be fixed?